# Need some help to figure out this issue related to NFT

Tags: solidity

suppose i have:

```
struct Features {
        uint256 _level;
        uint256 _strength;
    }

mapping(uint256 => Features) public tokenIdToFeatures;
```

Now i wanna set both feature from 2 different functions, like this:

```
 function getLevels(uint256 _tokenId) public returns (string memory) {
        level++;
       
        tokenToFeatures[_tokenId] = Features({_level: level})
        return level.toString();
    }
    
    function getStrength(uint256 _tokenId) public returns(string memory){
        strength++;
        tokenIdToFeatures[_tokenId] = Features({_strength: strength});
    }
```

Is it right approach? if not then what is the right approach?
N.B: As i creating a NFT so i will have to set this 2 features in 2 places, like this:

```
'<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet" viewBox="0 0 350 350">',
            '<style>.base { fill: white; font-family: serif; font-size: 14px; }</style>',
            '<rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="black" />',
            '<text x="50%" y="40%" class="base" dominant-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle">',
            "Warrior",
            "</text>",
            '<text x="50%" y="50%" class="base" dominant-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle">',
            "Levels: ",
            getLevels(_tokenId),
            "</text>",
            '<text x="50%" y="50%" class="base" dominant-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle">',
            "Levels: ",
            getStrength(_tokenId),
            "</text>",
            "</svg>"
```

That is why i created 2 different functions.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is close, but there are potential improvements you can make:

1. I suppose there's a typo in **getLevels** it should be **tokenIdToFeatures** instead of **tokenToFeatures**
2. I think it's better to update values like this:

   ```
   tokenIdToFeatures[_tokenId]._level++; // level++ isn't needed
   ...
   tokenIdToFeatures[_tokenId]._strength++; // strength++ isn't needed
   ```
3. You could use **event** to log the feature updates as it's common practice

Comment: Right, thanks, will my approach give error?

Comment: if you fix the typo, it wont give error